# Terraform GCP - NAT Gateway not creating

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform, google-cloud-networking

Using terraform to create nat-gateway using this module.
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/nat-gateway/google/1.1.3

using this code :

```
module "nat" {
        source                  = "GoogleCloudPlatform/nat-gateway/google"
        region                  = "${var.gcloud-region}"
        network                 = "${google_compute_network.vpc-network.name}"
        subnetwork              = "${google_compute_subnetwork.vpc-subnetwork-public.name}"
        machine_type    = "${var.vm-type-nat-gateway}"
}
```

## Other snippets :

```
variable "gcloud-region"                        { default = "europe-west1" }
variable "vm-type-nat-gateway"                  { default = "n1-standard-2"}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc-network" {
    name                        = "foobar-vpc-network"
    auto_create_subnetworks     = false
}


resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "vpc-subnetwork-public" {
    name                        = "foobar-vpc-subnetwork-public"
    ip_cidr_range               = "10.0.1.0/24"
    network                     = "${google_compute_network.vpc-network.self_link}"
    region                      = "${var.gcloud-region}"
    private_ip_google_access    = false
}
```

================

> - module.nat.google_compute_route.nat-gateway: 1 error(s) occurred:
> - module.nat.google_compute_route.nat-gateway: element: element() may not be used with an empty list in:
>
> ${element(split("/", element(module.nat-gateway.instances[0], 0)),
>   10)}

---

Above errror coming up and whole terraform script get stop , and unable to run

`terraform apply` or `terraform destroy` at any changes,

any possible issue causing this ?

Comment: I see you reported it in the issue tracker and it's been fixed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-nat-gateway/issues/19

Comment: Err, I just see the gihub issue is still open and this bit of code has not changed as I thought earlier. There is a proposed fix is in a fork https://github.com/sgirones/terraform-google-nat-gateway/commit/cbec3fb0dba2bdd7653557a2924cb66ba7f75eae. Did you try it?

Comment: This fixed the issue directly from the repo without any changes in my code level. Thanks. 
could you please add this as the answer ? @Matt-y-er

Comment: dose this requried any code level change  ? @Matt-y-er